# host.docker.internal vs container name when referencing ip

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When defining services in a docker-compose file, when do I use `host.docker.internal` for the host's ip and when do I need to use the container's name?

Comment: You should never need to use `host.docker.internal` to connect to another service defined in the same Compose file.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes what host names and configuration options are available.

Comment: @DavidMaze There's a passage saying: "The host has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network access). We recommend that you connect to the special DNS name host.docker.internal which resolves to the internal IP address used by the host. This is for development purpose and will not work in a production environment outside of Docker Desktop for Windows."

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/networking/

Comment: So the question is why will it not work in a production environment?

Comment: You wouldn't normally use a "desktop" type application in production.  Conversely, in production, I wouldn't be surprised to see things like databases on dedicated hardware or in cloud-hosted services, which also wouldn't be "the same host"; you need to make sure you have a good way to configure their location at deploy time.

Answer (score 7):

All possible communication flows are illustrated here :

[image]

(1) : non-containerized process **communicates** with a container

(2) : container **communicates** with another container

(3) : the opposite direction of (1)

---

(1): container must forward port to host, so the non-containerized process can access it

```yaml
services:
   c1:
    ...
     ports:
       - hostport:containerport
```

(2): container c1 just use the service name (container name - c2) to communicate with c2

(3): container c2 must Use the private IP of the host(`hostname -i`).

For (3), there are couple of points:

- Host Network range must not overlap with Docker network range, otherwise, Docker router will not throw the request out.
- Host must not enable firewall that blocks ports used by the non-containerized process.
- IF you are using Docker For Desktop, `host.docker.internal` is alias to the Host private IP. then you don't need to calculate the private IP of the host with `hostname -i`.

Comment: nicely illustrated - thx for the insights ;)

Comment: Welcome Man! :)

Comment: There's a passage saying: "The host has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network access). We recommend that you connect to the special DNS name host.docker.internal which resolves to the internal IP address used by the host. This is for development purpose and will not work in a production environment outside of Docker Desktop for Windows." docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/networking

Comment: So the question is why will it not work in a production environment?

Comment: Use private IP (`hostname -i`) of your host in production,, assuming there is overlap between network range of docker & host.

Comment: @YonatanNir answer is updated to make it more clear.

Comment: is it safe to say that when you run docker compose on a host with docker for desktop then actually everything is like option 2 in your drawing? And eventually isn't the host, even if not our personal pc, is still some kind of machine that can run Docker for Desktop and then we can still use host.docker.internal even on production?

Comment: is it safe to say that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect from a container to a service on the host, use `host.docker.internal`. Be aware, that this special DNS name is only available on Windows and macOS.

Use the container name for networking between containers.

Comment: But the containers are also on a host